# Enzyme Unit testing a component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I cant seem to get a basic unit test to run with enzyme.

```
describe('<Fixture />', () => {
    it("should the test",() => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Fixture />);
      expect(wrapper.find('#checked')).toBeChecked();
      expect(wrapper.find('#not')).not.toBeChecked();
    })
  });


function Fixture() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="checked" defaultChecked />
        <input id="not" defaultChecked={false} />
        <input id="tertiary" defaultChecked checked={false} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using the latest `react` at least from `v17` but still using the `v16` adapter `enzyme-adapter-react-16` since the `enzyme-adapter-react-16` is not compatible with the `react` `v17`.

But we have a work-around by using this package `@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17` as below:

```js
// Keep in mind install before using
// npm i -D @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17

// Simple set it up globally
const Adapter = require('@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17');

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```